# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /tmp/pip-install-jmd01buw/opencv-python

Tags: python, linux, opencv, imshow, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a face recognition script which only works in a virtual environment, when I run it normally it gives a segmentation error. But I have an OpenCV script which displays real time camera feed, and this script is only running outside the venv. I want the opencv script to display the name of the person in a box right under their face. (I am using  NVIDIA Jetson NANO linux machine)

Thanks in advance :D

When I run face_recognition.py, I get this error:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
This is when I run it outside the venv, it works fine in the venv.

When I run camera.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('cam_1', frame1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /tmp/pip-install-jmd01buw/opencv-python_ba4212a80915456bb7fda8067d2e693c/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```